# Shouldn't files in public dir bypass Laravel?

Tags: php, laravel, apache

I've a Laravel 8 project and when I add images in public/images they are not appearing in my webpage. When I go the the url of the image I sometimes get file not found, sometimes get some JSON, sometimes get the image, and sometimes get a completely different image in the same folder. It's bizarre, I can press refresh and get different results at different times.

I expected anything I put in /app/public which is where apache is set for document root to not even touch Laravel.

I doubt it's related but I'm also getting odd errors when I make changes to anonymous components. No problems with the code, if I go to a different browser it works. I only mention that in case it's related and tips someone off.

Any ideas? My .htaccess

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
<IfModule mod_negotiation.c>
    Options -MultiViews -Indexes
</IfModule>

RewriteEngine On

# Handle Authorization Header
RewriteCond %{HTTP:Authorization} .
RewriteRule .* - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization}]

# Redirect Trailing Slashes If Not A Folder...
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} (.+)/$
RewriteRule ^ %1 [L,R=301]

# Send Requests To Front Controller...
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]
```

Comment: Sounds like you're running into the browser cache; try clearing your cache or keeping dev tools open (with cache disabled) while testing

Answer (score 0):

You should include actual error message in your question to get a better understanding of the issue.

Anyway, it seems like you have not configured Apache `.htaccess` file properly to bypass laravel `index.php` file when the request url points to a file. Here is a example `.htaccess` code to be used in a Laravel project (put inside `/public` folder):

```
 <IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On

    # Handle Front Controller...
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]

    # Handle Authorization Header
    RewriteCond %{HTTP:Authorization} .
    RewriteRule .* - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization}]
</IfModule>
```

This will make Apache bypass Laravel and directly access the files for URLs like:
`http://www.example.com/images/1.jpg`

Comment: There is no error message, just unexpected content. Either not found, some json, or a random file from that folder. It's truly bizarre.